# Calling a view through id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have different files in `views` folder

in `navbar` folder I have

```
navbar-1
navbar-2
```

Now I am calling it dynamically by giving it an id like

```
@include('index_store.navbar.navbar-{{ $layout->navbar_id }}')
```

Where as

```
$layout->navbar_id = 1
```

But it says

```
View [index_store.navbar.navbar-<?php echo e($layout->navbar_id); ?>] not found.
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@include` directive is parsed to php code when rendering, so you have to concatenate the string like you would do any other string in php.

Like so:

```
@include('index_store.navbar.navbar-' . $layout->navbar_id)
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you I didn't know! Just have started laravel recently :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Good luck with Laravel, it is amazing! :D

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a syntax issue, try to write it like:

```
@include("index_store.navbar.navbar-{$layout->navbar_id}") // with double quotes
```

OR

```
@include("index_store.navbar.navbar-" . $layout->navbar_id)
```